# JavaScript: How is "function onload() {}" different from "onload = function() {}"?

Tags: javascript, scope

In the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), we read that `function f() {}` defines the name locally, while `[var] f = function() {}` defines it globally. That makes perfect sense to me, but there's some strange behavior that's different between the two declarations.

I made an HTML page with the script

```
onload = function() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

and it worked as expected. When I changed it to

```
function onload() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

nothing happened. (Firefox still fired the event, but WebKit, Opera, and Internet Explorer didn't, although frankly I've no idea which is correct.)

In both cases (in all browsers), I could verify that both `window.onload` and `onload` were set to the function. In both cases, the global object `this` is set to the window, and I no matter how I write the declaration, the `window` object is receiving the property just fine.

What's going on here? Why does one declaration work differently from the other? Is this a quirk of the JavaScript language, the DOM, or the interaction between the two?

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect this is a bug in Webkit/Opera and that Firefox has the correct behaviour.

Comment: Neither is correct per se. The global object (to which `window` refers) may have host defined properties (such as `onload`) and an ECMAScript 3 implementation is free to implement the behaviour of such a property as it sees fit, including the internal `[[Put]]` method that is called when the value of the property is assigned.

Comment: In Firefox 3.5.5, I see the alert if I use `onload = function() {...};` but not with `var onload = function() {...};`

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it's a miracle that this (non-standard functionality) works at all, and we should just use `window.addEventHandler` instead of messing around like this?

Comment: I'm not sure about a miracle, but based on the observed inconsistencies I'd certainly recommend against using the `var onload = ...` and `function onload() {...}` forms. `window.onload = function() {...};` is not part of any current standard but pretty universally much supported across browsers, as is `<body onload="...">`. A combination of `window.addEventListener` and `window.attachEvent` will allow you to add multiple event handlers in all the major browsers, but beware of differences between the two.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you might be interested to know why it's a good idea to avoid `onload = function(){...}` pattern — http://thinkweb2.com/projects/prototype/onloadfunction-considered-harmful/

Comment: @kangax: Good article. You've done the research I should've done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This two snippets declares a function in the current scope, named "onload". No binding is done.

```
function onload() { ... }
```

.

```
var onload = function() { ... }
```

This snippet assigns a function to a property/variable/field named "onload" on the current scope:

```
onload = function() { ... }
```

The reason why Firefox performed the binding and raised the onload event on the 1st snippet and the others didn't might be because the Firefox chrome (its user interface) itself is written and automated using JavaScript - that's why it's so flexible and easy to write extensions on it. Somehow, when you declared the locally-scoped `onload` function that way, Firefox "replaced" the `window`'s (most likely the local context at the time) implementation of `onload` (at that time, an empty function or undefined), when the other browsers correctly "sandboxed" the declaration into another scope (say, `global` or something).

Comment: Good observation that Firefox is written *in* JavaScript.

Comment: Well, not completely, but most of his chrome (user interface) is.

Answer (score 4):

Many people are correctly pointing out the global / local difference between (*UPDATE: Those answers have mostly been removed by their authors now*)

```
var x = function() {
```

and

```
function x() {
```

But that doesn't actually answer your specific question as you aren't actually doing the first one of these.

The difference between the two in your example is:

```
// Adds a function to the onload event
onload = function() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Whereas

```
// Declares a new function called "onload"
function onload() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because the latter gets evaluated at parse time, so the `window` object isn't quite ready to accept events yet?

Comment: Really? Assigning a function to `window.onload` works well in my experience.

Comment: According to the ECMAScript 3 spec, `var x = function() {...};` and `function x() {...}` should set properties of the same variable object, which in the case of global code is the global object, which is more or less equivalent to `window` in most browsers, so your answer doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Sohnee: my point was that there is no "global / local difference" between `var x = function() {...};` and `function x() {...}` declared in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is going on, based on Tim Down's helpful comments and a brief discussion with Jonathan Penn:

When the JavaScript interpreter assigns to the `window.onload` property, it's talking to an object that the browser has given it. The setter that it invokes notices that the property is called `onload`, and so goes off to the rest of the browser and wires up the appropriate event. All of this is outside the scope of JavaScript — the script just sees that the property has been set.

When you write a declaration `function onload() {}`, the setter doesn't get called in quite the same way. Since the declaration causes an assignment to happen at *parse* time, not evaluation time, the script interpreter goes ahead and creates the variable without telling the browser; or else the window object isn't ready to receive events. Whatever it is, the browser doesn't get a chance to see the assignment like it does when you write `onload = function() {}`, which goes through the normal setter routine.

Answer (score 0):

```
var onload = function() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Will declare it locally too.

I suggest you to read this very helpful article : http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: That's a great article, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest explanation:

```
function aaaaaaa(){
```

Can be used before it is declarated:

```
aaaaaaa();
function aaaaaaa(){

}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
aaaaaaa();
aaaaaaa=function(){

}
```

That's because in the third code, you are assigning aaaaaaa to an anonymous function, not declaring it as a function.

Answer (score -1):

This generates an error:

```
foo();
var foo = function(){};
```

This doesn't:

```
foo();
function foo(){}
```

The second syntax is therefore nicer when you're using functions to modularize and organize your code, whereas the first syntax is nicer for the functions-as-data paradigm.

Comment: This is an answer to [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname); it does not answer *this* question, which is about event bindings on `window`.